# What is the acceptable phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the acceptable phrase?

- No have enough seats
- Don't have enough seats

Comment: Please use complete sentences for your examples. Phrases out of context can have different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure either one is that great.  I would say it this way:

> "No, we don't have enough seats."

or

> "We don't have enough seats."

No. 1 is definitely wrong. No. 2 is rather rude.  I would never just say, "Don't have enough seats", because I'd be afraid of being punched in the face if I did say this.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the audience. An example;

Space is limited. Please reserve your seat now.

Limited Seats Available.

RSVP Now to Reserve your Seat.

Going Fast! Only A Few Seats Left! Reserve Now!

Reservations Reccomended to Accomodate Parties of 4 or More.

Comment: When would each of these be suitable or not?